# After deploying a custom field , will the old field name be overriden or a duplicate value be created?

Tags: custom-field

I have changed a custom field name of a custom object in one sandbox. After deploying it to the other sandbox, duplicate value ll be created or the values ll get overridden?

Also pls provide me for Workflow task and Email alert

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate values are created if you change the API name of fields. Additionally changing the name of workflow rules and email alerts also will duplicate when deploying from sandbox to production using changesets or the IDE.

Comment: Additionally, when changing only the label, no duplicate field will be created but the value will be overwritten.